# Why does "setCommandByIoctl failed" occur when I try to send data?

Tags: android, sockets

I am writing code to send data from client to server. However, when I try to send data to the server, I encounter the following error. I am convinced that the connection has been established. I have searched for info about the error on the Internet. However, nothing has encountered such error before.

Here is the logcat of the error:

```
W/e.magickeyboard: type=1400 audit(0.0:52635): avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=18094 path="/proc/18094/rtg" dev="proc" ino=1605802 ioctlcmd=0xab20 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
W/e.magickeyboard: type=1400 audit(0.0:52636): avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=18094 path="/proc/18094/rtg" dev="proc" ino=1605802 ioctlcmd=0xab20 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
W/e.magickeyboard: type=1400 audit(0.0:52637): avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=18094 path="/proc/18094/rtg" dev="proc" ino=1605802 ioctlcmd=0xab20 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0
W/e.magickeyboard: type=1400 audit(0.0:52638): avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=18094 path="/proc/18094/rtg" dev="proc" ino=1605802 ioctlcmd=0xab20 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
W/e.magickeyboard: type=1400 audit(0.0:52639): avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=18094 path="/proc/18094/rtg" dev="proc" ino=1605802 ioctlcmd=0xab20 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c182,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
D/RtgSchedIpcFile: setCommandByIoctl failed ret:-1, cmdid:32, errno:13
```

I do not know what this means.

Here is my client code to build a socket to connect to the server:

```
btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            
            mThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {                            
                        socket=new Socket("192.168.101.2",9102);
                        System.out.println(socket.isConnected());
                        boolean m=socket.isConnected();
                        if(m) {
                            Log.d("Connect","True");
                        }
                        if(!m){
                            Log.d("Connect","Connect false");
                        }


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Connect",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException e){
                        Log.d("Connect",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
                    catch(NetworkOnMainThreadException e){
                        Log.d("Connect",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Below is my client code to transfer data to the server:

```java
btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            mThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                
                        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                        outputStream.write(floatToByte(a));
                        outputStream.flush();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("send",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException e)
                    {
                        Log.d("send",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }

                }
```

Here is the code of my server:

```
try {
            
            ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(9102);
            
            Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
         
            InputStream is=socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String info=null;
            while(!((info=br.readLine())==null)){
                System.out.println("This is the server："+info);
            }
           
            OutputStream os=socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(os);
         
            String reply="welcome";
            pw.write(reply);
            pw.flush();
         
            pw.close();

            br.close();
            is.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

Comment: Please show the code that sets up the client's socket. I don't know what `ioctlcmd=0xab20` and `cmdid:32` refer to in this context, but `errno:13` is `EACCES` (Permission denied), so you (or the underlying socket provider) must be doing something your app is not allowed to do, but we can't see everything you are doing. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added my code of building a socket and I have provided a minimal reproducible example. Please help me with this. I have totally no idea why this would happen.@RemyLebeau